# Hide a page in the admin end without a plugin?

Tags: wp-admin, customization

I'm creating a series of pages with iFrames embedded in them, but it seems the only way to do this within Wordpress (i.e. using the templating system) is to create pages in the admin end and then create individual templates for each of those pages.

Is it possible to hide those pages from the admin without a plugin? I see no need for the client to see those pages when they can't edit anything in them.

Thanks,

osu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `parse_query` filter hook to exclude your pages using post__not_in attribute

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'exclude_pages_from_admin' );
function exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
    global $pagenow,$post_type;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type =='page') {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array('21','22','23');
    }
}
```

this will exclude pages with the ids of 21,22,23

and to make sure this pages will not be included on the front end using wp_list_pages
you can use wp_list_pages_excludes filter hook:

```
 add_filter('wp_list_pages_excludes', 'exclude_from_wp_list_pages');
 function exclude_from_wp_list_pages($exclude_array){
    $exclude_array = $exclude_array + array('21','22','23');
    return $exclude_array;
 }
```

Comment: If you globalise `$post_type` you'd not need to reference `$_GET` to check the post type(it does get reliably set for admin pages - unlike `$typenow`).

Comment: @t31os:  Thanks for the tip, i updated the code.

Comment: @Bainternet: Thanks for the nice bit of code. But the problem is: anything that is applicable for any lower roles, is also applicable for upper roles too. I added `&& current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )` to your code-snippet, but it's hiding pages from Admin role too. :( I want to hide pages only from the sight of Editor, none other. How can I?

Comment: Ok, got the solution: `&& current_user_can( 'editor' )`. `current_user_can()` also takes Admin role. :)