# get page id's - not get pages?

Tags: id

I'm trying to do something like this:
[Hide a page in the admin end without a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13528/hide-a-page-in-the-admin-end-without-a-plugin)

However, I don't want to hardcode the page-ids. I want to get the page id's based on template-name.

```
$pages = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'product.php'
));
```

^^This probably does the job, but it gets entire pages, and I start worrying about efficiency, especially when I only need id's and there could be thousands of pages being returned by this command.

I know SQL pretty well, so if I should just write my own query, then let me know.

Or maybe I don't need to worry about this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter `'fields'`:

```
$pages = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'  => 'page',
        'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'product.php',
        'fields'     => 'ids'
    )
);
```

*Not tested,* but it should fetch just the IDs.