# Hide pages depending on role

Tags: menus, pages, admin, wp-admin

I've been trying to find a way to limit the user from seeing some pages in the "pages" menu in the admin panel.

I looked in the edit.php file and noticed:

```
} elseif ( 'page' == $post_type ) {
```

However, i am unsure of what i need to edit in order to show **some** pages and hide others depending on the role.

The **Admin** will be able to see all posts.

The **SubAdmin** will only be able to see some pages.

How can i edit the edit.php file (or some other php file) in order to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To get the current role of the user

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
   return;
$roles = $current_user->roles;  //$roles is an array
```

After getting role set page ids which you want to show according to roles (for example)

```
    if($roles=='administrator'){
     $args=array('21','22','23');
    }

   or

   if($roles=='subscriber'){
     $args=array('24','25','26');
    }
```

you can use `parse_query` filter hook to exclude your pages using post__not_in attribute

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'exclude_pages_from_admin' );
function exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
    global $pagenow,$post_type;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type =='page') {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = $args
    }
}
```

**Important Links:**

- [Hide a page in the admin end without a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13528/hide-a-page-in-the-admin-end-without-a-plugin)
- [How to know the role of current user in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499104/how-to-know-the-role-of-current-user-in-wordpress)

Comment: Great, I was looking for a solution like this one. Basically hide posts and pages in the dashboard depending on role and post category. A few questions: will this work in WP 4.5.2? Where do I have to modify this and what will happen on updates? Thanks a lot